# how can i send query string in body of http request sampler ?(post request)

Tags: jmeter, query-string

I am sending query string in body of http request sampler. It is not getting correct response. Not Correctly sending data to server if query string.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31p7P.png)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to [HTTP POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) requests you need to specify URL query string under "Path" input field of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image]

In general the easiest way of building a correct HTTP Request sampler is just recording your scenario using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or in some cases [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/) might be easier to use